# React Native + Firebase Storage: base64 and blob not working

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm trying to use  to either encode my image file as base64 or blob, but neither of them are working. I'm also using this: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker to manage the image picker.

Try 1: Using Image picker's `.data` method, which is supposed to return a base64 string

```
const blah = uuid.v4();
firebase
  .storage()
  .ref('images')
  .child(`${blah}.jpg`)
  .putString(file.data, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/jpeg' })
```

But this throws: `Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found`

Try 2: Blob using https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob

```
      const uri = file.uri;
      const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri
      data = RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
      blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob.build(data, { type: 'application/octet-stream;BASE64' })
      const uniqueId = uuid.v4();
      const firebaseRef = firebase.storage().ref('images').child(`${uniqueId}.jpg`)
      return Observable.fromPromise(firebaseRef.put(blob, { contentType: 'application/octet-stream;BASE64' }));
    })
```

However, it is returning:  `Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in`put`at index 0: Expected Blob or File.`

Try 3: base64 using https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob

```
      const uri = file.uri;
      const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri
      data = RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
      const uniqueId = uuid.v4();
      const firebaseRef = firebase.storage().ref('images').child(`${uniqueId}.jpg`)
      const metadata= {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
      };
      firebaseRef.putString(data, 'base64', metadata);
```

But this again throws: `Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm running into this exact same issue. The really weird thing is that the .data works when the react native debugger is turned on

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day I used version 5.5.6 recently I updated to version 6.2.0 and ran to the same issue.

```
const uri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? response.uri.replace('file://', '') : response.uri
const imageRef = storage().ref('images/').child("blah")
await imageRef.put(uri)
const imageUrl = await imageRef.getDownloadURL()
```

I just changed `.put` to `.putFile` and everything worked again

Answer (score 0):

about (try 1) you have to use 'data_url':

```
.putString(file.data, 'data_url', { contentType: 'image/jpeg' })
```

Comment: There is a typo, the type is "DATA_URL"

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage#.StringFormat

BTW, the proper value is BASE64...

Comment: yes, sorry, it was a typo. when I wrote the answer, 'base64' did not work